# Can I post this question in the main site?

Tags: discussion, support

We are a small team working on a free open source Arduino playground. We would like to collect feedback from Arduino enthusiasts as well as beginners to make our project more useful. hence, we are very much interested to listen to the use cases, user wishes or needs, feedback on the simulator, and feature feedback.

**is it possible to ask the question on the main site so that we can reach more Arduino users?**

Here is the links of the project:

https://wokwi.com/arduino/libraries

https://github.com/wokwi/arduino-libraries

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No. The main site is not a place for soliciting feedback for projects - it is a place for obtaining help with specific problems you may be having.

There's nothing stopping you asking on Meta - though the audience is considerably smaller, so the results may be pretty meaningless.

Comment: is here a possibility for moderator to add [featured] tag to show the meta question on the right yellow bar on main?

Comment: Meta is really for "questions about the site" - I don't see how this is really a question about the site.

Comment: @Juraj Nah, I don't think so. That would be no different to posting on the main site really. And yeah, Nick, I do agree with that - but moderation is much looser here as there are only about 4 people who ever read meta...

Comment: You, me, Juraj, and who is the 4th? :)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you post on [the Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/), possibly in [Gigs and Collaborations](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=26.0), [Products and Services](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=25.0) or [Exhibition / Gallery](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=29.0) (but only one of those).